# Should I use "will" or omit it in following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Now I'm pondering on the details of me fulfilling an elaborate plan,thinking that it works well.                                                                 (In this sentence,would it make sense if I add "will" after "it"? Or both way are fine?)

Answer (score 1):

...thinking that it **will work well**

As the plan is apparently only in the thinking stage, you would need to use the future tense, and use the bare infinitive "work", not third-person singular present ("works")

Answer (score -1):

Will should, as far as I'm concerned, definitely be added as it adds the notion of futurity.